# Creating a program that works out if the word is in ascending order or not

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java and have recieved some feedback on my tutor from my work on a program that works out if a word is in ascending order but I don't really understand it. Could anyone help to explain? I'm sorry if it's obvious to others. The feedback is in the comments below.

```
class Main
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    System.out.print( "#Please enter a name : " );
    String name = BIO.getString();
    while(!name.equals("END")){

        Boolean inOrder = true;

            String nameLC = name.toLowerCase();
            char previous = name.charAt(0);
            for (int x = 0; x < nameLC.length() && inOrder ; x++) {
                inOrder = nameLC.charAt(x) >= previous;
                // inOrder must only be set false
                previous = nameLC.charAt(x);
            }

            // The problem is you only want to set inOrder to be false
            // If you set it to true as well then you will cancel out
            // a possible previous finding of that two letters were out of order


            if (inOrder && !name.equals("END"))
            {
                System.out.print(name + "\t" + "letters in ascending order");
            }
            else if (!inOrder && !name.equals("END"))
            {   
                System.out.print(name + "\t" + "letters not in ascending order");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");

            System.out.print("#Please enter a name : ");
            name = BIO.getString();

    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Explain. What exactly do you have a question about? Please be more detailed and ask exact questions.

Comment: Programs works as expected to find a word as ascending or not. i think inOrder variable set in the for loop condition was overlooked by your tutor. or is there any other comment has been given like Upper case, last name etc.,

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int x = 0; x < nameLC.length(); x++) {
            inOrder = nameLC.charAt(x) >= previous;
            if(!inOrder) break;
            previous = nameLC.charAt(x);
        }
```

If I got you right you want to exit in case one letter is not "in order".
Just add this "break;" statement to your loop and you should be fine.

Greetings Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you step through your program by hand for a short name that's partially in order then you'll see the problem.

E.g. "bar":

When you get to "a", since "a" < "b", you set inOrder to false.

After this you should exit the loop and return false, but what you actually do is go on to process the "r", and since "r" > "a", you set inOrder to true.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your solution *already* breaks if `inOrder` is set to false. You have a compound condition in your `for`-loop that exits when `inOrder` is false.

```
for(int x = 0; // Initialize x
    x < nameLC.length() && inOrder; // Continue looping UNTIL x == nameLC.length() OR inOrder is false
    x++){ // Increment x
    inOrder = nameLC.charAt(x) >= previous; // Set inOrder, if it's false the for loop will exit
```